# cannot save ArrayList to sharedpreferences

Tags: kotlin, android-recyclerview

I try to save an arrayList to sharedPreferences so as to load to recyclerview each time i enter the recyclerview activity, but it does not seem to work. I use a custom ClothModel and also i use gson library. Does sb can solve this issue?  My code is below

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view)

    val recyclerView: RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(applicationContext)

    clothesAdapter = ClothesAdapter(clothList)

    recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
    recyclerView.itemAnimator = DefaultItemAnimator()
    recyclerView.adapter = clothesAdapter

    var bitmapStr = intent.getStringExtra("bitmapStr")

    thread {
        val url = URL(bitmapStr)
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream())
        this.runOnUiThread {
            prepareClothData()
        }
    }
}


private fun saveClothList() {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = sharedPreferences.edit()
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = gson.toJson(clothList)
    editor.putString("clothlist", json)
    editor.apply()
}

private fun loadClothList() {
    val sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE)
    val gson = Gson()
    val json = sharedPreferences.getString("clothlist", null)
    val type: Type = object : TypeToken<ArrayList<ClothModel1>>() {}.type
    clothList = gson.fromJson(json, type)

    if (clothList == null) {
        clothList = ArrayList()
    }
}


private fun prepareClothData() {

    try {
        loadClothList()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
    }

    val cloth = ClothModel1("title", bitmap)
    clothList.add(cloth)

    saveClothList()

    clothesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the debugger to break on the line `clothList = gson.fromJson(json, type)` to see if `clothList` is populated as you expect. Also, it seems that you are recreating `clothList` with that line of code but do not inform the *RecyclerView* that it has a new data set to work with. See [RecyclerView#swapAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html#swapadapter) and [RecyclerView#setAdapter()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView#setadapter).